# Conflict between jquery and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code where I am including jquery files and bootstrap files in the header.php. I am running into issues where if I include the jquery file before bootstrap.js file, it messes up the other tabs on my webpage and basically even if i click on the other tabs it does not navigate me.

I think there is a conflict between jquery and bootstrap. I am pasting my header.php file below for more reference.

header.php

```
<?php require_once "essentials.php";
//error_reporting(~0);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!--<style>{height:150px; width:1300px;}</style>-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="Public">
<title><?php echo $page_title?></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="script_dbafactory.js?<?php echo rand(0,511);?>"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<link href="css/style_header.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-4 column">
                        <img alt="logo" src="./images/source.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 column dbf">
                        <h2>
                                DBA Factory
                        </h2>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                        <div class="tabbable" id="tabs-775712">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                         <li>
                                                <a href="../dbafactory/home_page.php?sub=1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="../dbafactory/form_page.php?sub=2" data-toggle="tab">Submit a project</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="../dbafactory/view_table.php?sub=3" data-toggle="tab">All Projects</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="#panel-4" data-toggle="tab">Innovative Ideas</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="#panel-5" data-toggle="tab">Matchmaker</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
          <a href="#panel-6" data-toggle="tab">Meet the Team</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <div class="dropdown">
                                        <?php include "userlogin.php"; ?>
                                        </div>
                                </ul>

                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>


</div>
</body>

<!--<script type="text/javascript">
//Script to implement tabs 
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})

</script>-->
<script>
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function (){
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        $('#userlogin').dropdown('toggle');
});
</script>
```

Can someone please let me know how do i solve this issue? and how should i load all the js and css files to avoid any issues with the webpage.

Thanks

Comment: bootstrap version used?

Comment: You can't have a `<div class="dropdown">` in your `UL`..

Comment: bootstrap 3.1.0 - latest one @ArunPJohny

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - the dropdown is working fine for me...except for the positioning...the button is on extreme right and the dropdown menu on extreme left

Comment: @rond because you can't have a `div` in an `ul` without it being wrapped by an `li`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - I will fix that issue afterwards...the primary one is the conflict here..if i load the jquery file first it messes the page and basically i cant navigate between tabs...can we work on that?

Comment: You're using jQuery UI with Bootstrap......why?

Comment: can you help recreating the issue in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L7Rdm/1/

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - okay..i dont know that..I should not use jqueryUI with bootstrap?

Comment: @ArunPJohny - http://jsfiddle.net/rohan2911/E2dbB/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

data-toggle="tab" for bootstrap means there has to have a [tab panel] for it, however, you only use it as nav, and it caused the problem.

Please read: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Also, use js closure can more easier to avoid js conflict issue:

```
(function($){
    ....
})(jQuery);
```

Please check the code below, you can use WinMerge to compare the code with your own:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!--<style>{height:150px; width:1300px;}</style>-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="Public">
<title><?php echo $page_title ?></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<link href="css/style_header.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-4 column">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 column dbf">
                        <h2>
                                DBA Factory
                        </h2>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                        <div class="tabbable" id="tabs-775712">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                         <li>
                                                <a href="#panel-4">Home</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="#panel-4">Submit a project</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="#panel-4">All Projects</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="#panel-4">Innovative Ideas</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="#panel-5">Matchmaker</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                                <a href="#panel-6">Meet the Team</a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a id="userlogin" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">rdesai<span class="caret"</span></a>

                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="userlogin">
                                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                </ul>

                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function (){
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
            $('#userlogin').dropdown('toggle');
    });

})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have commented the ui JS file..still no difference :(

Comment: can you load bootstrap at footer of your html? Bootstrap suggested it.

Comment: Besides, bootstrap is for HTML5, so your `XHTML 1.0 Transitional` maybe a issue

Comment: I loading the bootstrap right before the </body> tag but no luck. The tabs start working but the dropdown stops working :( Me too think I may have to include HTML5..any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Please read: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template and follow the structure.

Comment: i changed it according to the Template...still no luck..@Zac

Comment: Please paste your dropdown in html, like the html sample export for `userlogin.php`, by the way I updated my answer

Comment: I made the code same..but still the same problem..I see the following error in Firebug @Zac `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:` ' 

throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );' when I click on a new tab.

Comment: Remove [ data-toggle="tab"]

Comment: Nope..still does not work...I am not sure now...where is the issue... @Zac

Comment: Works now! I missed out on one `data-toggle="tab"`. Can you please explain why was this causing an issue? @Zac

Comment: @rond as you wish, please check the answer

Answer (score 5):

Usually when i run into jquery and bootstrap conflicts, i just add this as the first line of my php file:

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

This is to avoid conflicts with other libraries.

You can read more here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

**Edit:**

Or use

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

instead of 1.10.3

Comment: to be more precise within <head>...</head> tags?

Comment: how about using jquery-ui bootstrap 1.10.2 instead of 1.10.3?

Comment: Can you please give me the link from where to download?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> you don't have to download just change to this.

Comment: in addition to calling noConflict inside your first line of BODY, try using 'jQuery' instead of '$' sign.

Comment: and if nth works, save yourself and use https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-ui-bootstrap.

Comment: `.noConflict()` is a jQuery method to avoid conflicts between other libraries using `$` as an alias for something else. Bootstrap components are built on top of jQuery, so this has nothing to do with conflicts between jquery and bootstrap