# jquery bootstrap collapse has Class in not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm really stuck on this one.
After trying to figure it out for more than a day
 I really be grateful for some help.
I'm using a bootstrap collapse navigation and I want to change the opacity of an other element if the navbar isn't collapsed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 $nav = $('.collapse');
 if ($nav.hasClass('in')) {
  $('#slider').css({opacity: 0.2});
 } 

});
```

I really have no clue what's wrong here. If I change .hasClass to ('collapse') it works but that's not what I want.

Things I also tried:

- `$nav.attr("aria-expanded", "true")` --> only works if false
- `$nav.css("display" == "block")` --> no effect
- `$nav.is(":visible")` --> no effect
- $nav = `$('#navigation'); $('#slider').css("opacity","0.2");`
- and I also tried to write it that way:

[Conflict between jquery and bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592734/conflict-between-jquery-and-bootstrap)

for the case of a conflict

Comment: Chances are that "in" class might be added after your code is executed. Maybe some other script adds "in" class,

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. Yes, that's what I am guessing, too.
But in my header my custom.js comes after jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js. And I also tried to write it in a <script></script> just before the </body>.

Comment: Try using a timer in your code. execute your code after some time to check if this is the issue or not

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I set a timeout it works.
Now I will have to figure out how I can execute the function straight after the "in" class has been added. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Its okay. Glad it worked for you and saved your time\

Comment: Thanks again for leading me the way.
For the case that somebody has the same problem the best solution for me is:
$nav.on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
 $('#slider').css({opacity: 0.2}); 
  });